# Android API level used to compile the project is not supported by the MobileFirst Platform Studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am building my MobileFirst 7.0 (**MF Version 7.0.0.00.20150312-0731 Consumer Edition**) Hybrid application through "`app-builder`" ant task. During the build process it is giving me below warning:

```
[app-builder] Apr 08, 2015 10:23:05 AM com.worklight.builder.sourcemanager.handlers.android.AndroidManifestSourceHandler checkBuildTarget
[app-builder] WARNING: FWLST1119W: Android build will fail because the API level used to compile the project is not supported by the MobileFirst Platform Studio.
[app-builder] It is recommended to use Android API level 21 which is the latest API level supported by the IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio. Use the Android SDK Manager to install API level 21, configure your project to build with API level 21 by updating the Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog.
[app-builder] Apr 08, 2015 10:23:10 AM com.worklight.ant.builders.ApplicationBuilderTask execute
[app-builder] SUCCESS: FWLST2001I: Successfully built environments: [common, ipad, android, iphone]
```

I have configured API my project to use API level 21, even then it is giving me the same warning. Is there any other place where I have to change the API level?

Following are the changes I made:

```
AndroidManifest.xml : <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

project.properties : target=android-21

Project Build Target in Project / Properties / Android dialog : Target Name: 5.0.1, API Level : 21
```

Comment: You probably need to update the minSdkVersion.

Comment: @IdanAdar I tried that also. Its giving me same warning.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari do you have the API 21 installed (Android 5.0.1)? You can check that through your Android SDK Manager.

Comment: @YoelNunez yes its installed.

Comment: My only other thought is that you're using an older Ant builder jar file?

Comment: @IdanAdar I am using the jars which are provided by MobileFirst 7.0. Besides, there is a check in worklight-ant-builder jar which won't allow me to build MF7.0 artifacts if I use older jars.

Comment: Okay, despite the warning - does the build pass or fail? It might just be an erroneous warning, but everything is still fine...

Comment: @IdanAdar build is not getting failed. Its just the warning that concern me since all the configuration is correct.

Comment: I believe this is a false positive and you can ignore it. We will check it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the build is not actually failing and the end product is still functioning, I tend to believe this is a false positive and the warning can be ignored.

It most likely is being generated erroneously.
This will be investigated regardless.

Answer (score 0):

in case of the build failed Maximo anywhere need specific Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK Tools and API try to know the correct versions compatible with your version of anywhere you can review this link:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOBy7UFdPupdUa_d1_4eztcUqIEICubJX
this link shows you Maximo anywhere 7.6.3 installation steps from start to end it may help you